# How can I a texture to a json model exported from Blender to Three.js?

Tags: json, three.js, blender, texture-mapping

In this case, I create two spheres in the scene. One is a SphereGeometry of Three.js(the left one), the other is a json model from Blender(the right one).
Both of them use the same material and it does work. As follows:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff
});
```

[image: Using color white]

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    wireframe: true
});
```

[image: Using wireframe]

I try to add a texture to both of them.

However, the mapping effect does not work on the surface of the json model(the right one).

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: texture,
});
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Here are my [Demo](https://iceleaf97.github.io/QandA/JsonMap/phongMtl.html) and [source code](https://github.com/iceleaf97/QandA/blob/master/JsonMap/phongMtl.js).

Comment: in `models/ball.json` the data for "uvs":[] is empty so no texture

Comment: I did not use the material from Blender. I used the MeshPhongMaterial of three.js.

Comment: Thank you! gaitat!   I got what you mean. I have to do the UV procedure in the Blender. Then, the "uvs" array has complete uv information. It does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check the UVs option in the Blender Three.js exporter:

[image: Three.js = :(]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I always check [the UVs option](https://github.com/iceleaf97/QandA/blob/master/JsonMap/images/channel.png). Unfortunately it does not work.....

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
I have to unwrap a UV sphere in Blender first.

Just like this video.

[How To Unwrap A UV Sphere In Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U)

After this step, the json file has complete information of the UVs array and mapping effect does work.

[image]